# Magento Setup Script or install script won't work

Tags: php, magento-1.9, zend-db

I'm trying to run a simple install script that create table in the database however the table wasn't created but the install script was present.

This is my config.xml

```
<modules>
    <Rts_Pmadmin>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Rts_Pmadmin>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <Rts_Pmadmin>
            <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model</class>
            <resourcemodel>pmadmin_resource</resourcemodel>
        </Rts_Pmadmin>
        <pmadmin_resource>
            <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <pricematrix>
                    <table>pricematrix</table>
                </pricematrix>
            </entities>
        </pmadmin_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <pricematrix_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Rts_Pmadmin</module>
                <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </pricematrix_setup>
        <pricematrix_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </pricematrix_write>
        <pricematrix_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </pricematrix_read>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
        <Rts_Pmadmin>
            <class>Rts_Pmadmin_Helper</class>
        </Rts_Pmadmin>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

This is my install script mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('pmadmin/pricematrix')}` (
  `pricematrix_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` text,
  `post` text,
  `date` datetime default NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pricematrix_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `{$installer->getTable('pmadmin/pricematrix')}` VALUES (1,'My New Title','This is a blog post','2009-07-01 00:00:00','2009-07-02 23:12:30');
");
 $installer->endSetup();
```

This are my models

app/code/local/Rts/Pmadmin/Model/Resource

```
class Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Pricematrix extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('pmadmin/pricematrix');
}
}
```

app/code/local/Rts/Pmadmin/Model/Resource

```
class Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Resource_Pricematrix extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('pmadmin/pricematrix', 'pricematrix_id');
}
}
```

app/code/local/Rts/Pmadmin/Model/Resource

```
class Rts_Pmadmin_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {
}
```

How do I run the install script in a right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After few days of debugging. Finally I found the solution.

In the models node, the tag **resourcemodel** should be **resourceModel** with capital **M**.

In the sql dir, the sub folder **name** should match the resources pricematrix_setup tag, in my case **pricematrix_setup**.

Finally, Check your sql install script syntax if you have SQL syntax.

I hope this helps others.

Thanks!